# Weird behavior of reduceByKeyAndWindow function in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, spark-streaming, word-count

I am using spark 1.6 and came across this function reduceByKeyAndWindow which I am using to perform word count over data transmitted over a kafka topic.

Following is the list of alternatives reduceByKeyAndWindow is providing. As we can see, all the alternatives has similar signatures with extra parameters.

[image: List of Functions]

But when I just use reduceByKeyAndWindow with my reduce function or with my reduce function and duration, it works and doesn't give me any errors as shown below.

[image: No errors or warnings here]

But when I use the alternative with reduce function, duration and sliding window time it starts giving me the following error, same happens with the other alternatives, as shown below.

[image: Error message recieved]

I am not really sure what is happening here and how can I fix the problem.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Minutes(10), Seconds(2), 2)` this one works for me..

Comment: answered for your problem...

Answer (score 1):

If you comment this line `.words.map(x => (x, 1L))` you should be able to use the method [`.reduceByWindow(_+_, Seconds(2), Seconds(2))`] from `DStream`.

If you transform the words to words with count, then you should use the below method.

```
reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Minutes(10), Seconds(2), 2)
```

Please see the documentation on more details for what are those `reduce function` and `inverse reduce` function https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala

Comment: The thing is, if you see the list of functions available to me, I have the signature of the function without the inverse reduce function as well, so technically it should work.
As it doesn't work, can you explain why isn't it working and what the error messages mean?